# certificate ending layout

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

[image: certificate layout]

How can I achive the above layout in latex? `Place` and `Name` should be on the same horizontal line, and so as `Date` and `En.No.`. `Signature`, `Name` and `En.No` should come on a same vertical line.

Comment: Did you try to achieve it with the `{tabular}` environment? Which problems did you encounter?

Comment: Are »Name« and »Date« given from the commands for the `\maketitle` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do this without using the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\certificateending[4]{%
        \par
        \noindent
        \hskip.5\linewidth
        \hbox{\textbf{Signature of the Scholar}}\\
        \hbox to.5\linewidth{\textbf{Place:} #1\hfil}%
        \hbox{\textbf{Name: #2}}\\
        \hbox to.5\linewidth{\textbf{Date:} #3\hfil}%
        \hbox{\textbf{En.\ No: #4}}%
        \par
}
\begin{document}
\certificateending{Some Place}{John Doe}{11 December 2010}{56784332}
\end{document}
```

However, I don't think I'd make "John Doe" and "56784332" bold.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum to the answers posted. Here is a small macro that provides a line for a signature which comes handy in similar applications.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\sig#1#2{\vbox{\hsize=5.5cm
    \kern2cm\hrule\kern1ex
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #1 \hfil}
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #2 \hfil}}}

\begin{document}

\sig{John Doe}{En. No: 56784332}

\end{document}
```

[image: signature line]